# Namespace class name included conflict

Tags: php

I'm building a namespace which uses the same class name as a class that I'm including into the namespace.

```
require_once 'MyClass.php'; // already declares a class MyClass

namespace foo;

class MyClass {}
class MySubClass extends MyClass {}
```

How exactly would I do this without getting a "you cannot redeclare class..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the namespace declaration must be the first statement; and when you do this, it will just work:

```
namespace foo;

require_once 'MyClass.php'; // already declares a class MyClass

class MyClass {}
class MySubClass extends MyClass {}
```

Now, `\MyClass` refers to the class you have declared in `MyClass.php` (assuming it was declared without a specific namespace) whereas `MyClass` refers to the one inside the current namespace.

Alternatively, you can alias it:

```
namespace foo;

use MyClass as StdMyClass;

require_once 'MyClass.php'; // already declares a class MyClass

class MyClass {}
class MySubClass extends MyClass {}
```

In this case `StdMyClass` can be seen as an alias of `\MyClass`.

Comment: I see, so in order to use the class in MyClass.php, I would have to use \StdMyClass

Comment: @user3448187 Hmm, you want to use `foo\MyClass` inside `MyClass.php`? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: no, another library file uses it. AnotherClass.php uses MyClass.php, so I believe it's okay.

Comment: @user3448187 Okay, do let me know if you're confused about anything else :)